# How do I scrape the style of a class using r?

Tags: r, web-scraping

TLDR; The data I want to scrape is not in the html, but rather, within the style info for each element.

To start with, the site is a subscription site so I can't share a link to it. Sorry.

I'm attempting to scrape a map with locations plotted on it. It is created via javascript. I'm able to generate the correct maps with RSelenium. However, the data I'm looking to scrape isn't shown in the html. Here's a paired down version of the html.

```
<div class="map">
    <img alt="detailed_map" src="/images/detailed_map.svg">
        <div class="styled__Container-1ji7kn-0 fhUusb">
            <a class="lzWHb jdYxeo location"></a>
            <a class="lzWHb kNtaFB location"></a>
            <a class="lzWHb ldvwAI location"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

In Developer Tools in chrome, when I right-click on the element and select "Copy > Copy styles" I am able to find the data. Here is an example from one of the location elements. I eventually want to grab the left and top data.

```
line-height: 1.42;
font-family: "PT Sans";
font-size: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
left: 43.2381%;
top: 86.7647%;
width: 8px;
height: 8px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #8bcd4e;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

I'm sure there is additional info that I will need to supply to help, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to locate the css stylesheet used and use a css parser to interpret it in R. For example: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highlight/versions/0.5.0/topics/css.parser. Then find the classes of the elements you are interested in in this parsed css object.

Comment: Thanks @Bas. I'll look into it. The further I dig the more it looks like I need to understand how javascript is producing the data so that I can find the relevant css files. This will be helpful when I find the css files!